# Relationship between WMS styles and layers parameters for GetMap request in WMS 1.3.0?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, wms, mapserver, ogc

Here is the description which I copied from GeoServer:

```
layers  Yes Layers to display on map. Value is a comma-separated list of layer names.
styles  Yes Styles in which layers are to be rendered. Value is a comma-separated list of style names, or empty if default styling is required. Style names may be empty in the list, to use default layer styling.
```

However, I have questions:

1. Can 1 layer have multiple styles applied on it for just 1 GetMap request? e.g: `layers=world_map&styles=style1,style2,style3` (with `style1`, `style2` and `style3` belong to world_map layer)
2. Can multiple layers have only 1 style (i.e: this style is applied to all input layers or just the layer1)? e.g: `layers=layer1,layer2,layer3,...&styles=style1` (with `style1` belong to `layer1`)
3. Can the number of layers and the number of styles be different? e.g: `layers=layer1,layer2&style=style1,style2,style3,style4,style5`? (with `style1` and `style2` belong to `layer1`, `style3`, `style4` and `style5` belong to `layer2`).

I think these 3 cases are valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [WMS 1.3.0 specification](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wms) says in section 7.3.3.4:

> The mandatory STYLES parameter lists the style in which each layer is to be rendered. The value of the STYLES parameter is a comma-separated list of one or more valid style names. There is a one-to-one correspondence between the values in the LAYERS parameter and the values in the STYLES parameter. Each map in the list of LAYERS is drawn using the corresponding style in the same position in the list of STYLES.

So the answers are no, no, and no.

Comment: Thanks, that is easier to remember 1 Layer - 1 Style

Comment: The styles parameter isn't mandatory if a style is provided as part of an SLD_BODY or SLD parameter.  You can have additive styles for a layer when you specify both a Style and a SLD or SLD_BODY parameter.